# Yii get current logged user

Tags: php, yii

To get current user I use `Yii::app()->user->name`  it's ok when I'm logged as a user.

But when cron job executin command and try `Yii::app()->user->name` it's get *Property "CConsoleApplication.user" is not defined..*

How to get check inside my method does `Yii::app()` `user` os defined

I'm try use `isset()` but still getting same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, you can't use CWebUser in console application.

If you rely on a component, which needs CWebUser, you'll have to detect this in the component and create some kind of workaround for this case. For example, you could genereate in your scope code an  exception part where ensures that `Yii::app()->user` is not called:

```
 public function scopes(){
         if (Yii::app() instanceof CConsoleApplication) {
              $user = array(''); //no condition 
         }else{
              $user = array(
                        'condition'=>'id='.Yii::app()->user->id, 
                      );
         }
         return array(
              'user'    => $user,
              'active'  => array(
                                   'condition'=>'status='.self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                           ), ...
         );
 }
```

Another simple isset() check that works for me:

```
if (!isset(Yii::app()->user))
        echo "username not set\n";
return;
```

Console output:

[image]